# UIWebView: Delegate won't be called

Tags: objective-c

I try to calculate the size of a UIWebView with a given content, but without showing the view.  I only need to know the size.

My Problem: When I execute the code, the delegate of the UIWebView isn't called. Why?

MessageSizeCaluclator.h

```
#import < Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Message;

@interface MessageSizeCaluclator : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate>

- (id)initWithMessage:(Message*)message;
- (void)saveSize;

@end
```

MessageSizeCaluclator.m

```
#import "Message.h"
#import "MessageSizeCaluclator.h"


@interface MessageSizeCaluclator () <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) Message* message;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView* webView;

@end


@implementation MessageSizeCaluclator

@synthesize message = _message;
@synthesize webView = _webView;


- (id)initWithMessage:(Message*)message
{
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    _message = message;

    // WebView
    _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
    _webView.delegate = self;
}

return self;
}

- (void)saveSize
{
NSLog(@"%s message = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, _message.text);

[_webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='font-family:Helvetica;font-size:13px;'>This is a test</div>", _message.text]
                                 baseURL:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Web view delegate

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

Implementation

```
    MessageSizeCaluclator* messageSizeCalculator = [[MessageSizeCaluclator alloc] initWithMessage:message];
    [messageSizeCalculator saveSize];
```

Comment: At the point your code is called, there is no view, any reason why you aren't doing this in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Tim `MessageSizeCaluclator` isn't a view controller, it's just an object that instantiates a web view.

Comment: Ah my mistake, didn't read the interface declaration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add your UIWebView to some `UIView`, make its frame offscreen (so users can't see it). The delegate methods won't be called if `UIWebView` is not in the view hierarchy of the app.

Comment: +1 This sounds about right. Until the web view is part of a view hierarchy, loading data is just a waste of time and battery power.